# How to create encrypted HFS+ partitions on Big Sur?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, big-sur, hfs+

The *Disk Utility* application in MacOS Big Sur (11.0.1 (20B29)) no longer provide the option to create "MacOS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)" partitions.

Is there any other way to create HFS+ Journaled Encrypted partitions under Big Sur without needing to boot up Catalina (or booting up a VM containing one)?

HFS+ is still useful for rotational drives, since APFS' [performance on these mechanical disks](https://bombich.com/blog/2019/09/12/analysis-apfs-enumeration-performance-on-rotational-hard-drives) are rather abysmal. These drives are still very much useful and a cost-effective option for storing large amounts of data.

Comment: Can't you right-click on the volume in Finder and encrypt it from there?

Comment: Last time I did that, it converted the partition into APFS.

Comment: Indeed (I just tried) :-(

Comment: I'd appreciate an answer too. Also here right-clicking an HFS+ volume and then choosing "Encrypt" auto converts it to APFS.